# Homebrew on Mac not using the edited opencv.rb file via brew edit opencv during installation

Tags: macos, opencv, operating-system, homebrew

I tried to install opencv on Mac using Homebrew and edited the opencv.rb file using brew edit

opencv to change -DBUILD_opencv_text=OFF to -DBUILD_opencv_text=ON. However, it seems that the

installation process used the opencv.rb file configured in git instead of the edited one.

As a result, I cannot find the "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.7.0_3/share/java" folder after the

installation completed.

Below are the results of the brew info and brew doctor commands:
MacBookPro ~ % brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build trouble and cause formulae that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run the `brew link` on these:
opencv

Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew/homebrew-core.
If this is a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core && git stash -u && git clean -d -f

Uncommitted files:
M Formula/opencv.rb

Warning: Homebrew's "sbin" was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting your PATH for example like so:
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Warning: Your Xcode (14.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 14.3 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

What can I do to solve this problem?

p.s
[Ant is already installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmo7Q.png)

1. brew edit opencv
2. -DBUILD_opencv_text=OFF > DBUILD_opencv_text=ON
3. brew install --build-from-source opencv
4. [Log ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnAU0.png)
   ==> Fetching opencv
   ==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/69e9dc686649117e61ab8fe0d82be1def367f25c/Formula/opencv.rb

[install After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IDxy.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, every time you edit the formula with `brew edit formula` and then reinstall from source, it downloads again a new formula so it won't take in considerations your edit of `-DBUILD_opencv_text=ON`.
So, what you can do is install opencv with homebrew with by providing a local formula.

1. Download
   [formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/283d456cf5da85bb01e3be8b01044279f40c35f7/Formula/opencv.rb) wherever you want
2. Make the desired changes with a text editor
3. brew install --build-from-source /yourPath/opencv.rb

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
After 9 hours, I will try with the answer and share the result.
However, there is a memory that I have already tried like the answer you mentioned two days ago.

"brew install /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/opencv.rb"

Comment: The path is a path with an open.rb that has been changed by going to edit.
When the above command was executed, the following error occurred. TT

Comment: MacBookPro ~ % brew install /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/opencv.rb
Error: Failed to load cask: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/opencv.rb
Cask 'opencv' is unreadable: wrong constant name # <Class: 0x00007fb314a95af0>
Warning: Treating /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/opencv.rb as a formula.
== Fetching Opencv
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/opencv/manifests/4.7.0_1

Anyway, I'll try again in nine hours....

Comment: P.S. Thank you so much for your reply, I've been suspended for 3 days due to this problem.

Comment: @miniminime were you able to finally install it?

Comment: Two error logs occurred, but we were able to obtain an opencv-470.jar.

Comment: Error: Failed to load cask: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/opencv.rb
Cask 'opencv' is unreadable: wrong constant name #<Class:0x00007fbb99960e18>

Comment: Warning: opencv 4.7.0_4 is available and more recent than version 4.7.0_1.

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked. The first error simply tells you that cannot load the cask, and then go ahead with the local formula you provide.
The warning simply inform you about a newer version. Please accept my answer if I was able to resolve your issue. Thank you!